# React Native -- Loop through array of objects to return value

Tags: react-native, reactjs, jsx

Data:

```
{
                "contextTag": {
                    "value": "Bittersweet",
                    "valueLabel": "Bittersweet"
                },
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "tag",
                        "value": "Creamy"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "tag",
                        "value": "Colorful"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "tag",
                        "value": "Bright"
                    }
                ],
                "rating": 5,
                "userNickName": "HelloGames",
                "userLocation": "UK",
                "title": "Great!",
                "reviewText": "Yada yada yada yada",
                "submissionTime": "30 Nov 16"
},
```

I currently have this working for getting contextTag valueLabels:

```
this.props.reviewData.reviews.map(
                (o) => {
                    return o.contextTag && o.contextTag.valueLabel ? o.contextTag.valueLabel.trim() : '';
                }
            )
```

And this for tags:

```
this.props.reviewData.reviews.map(
                (o) => {
                    return o.tags && o.tags.value ? o.tags.value.trim() : '';
                }
            )
```

But it's coming back empty. How do I loop through tags to grab each of the values?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the tags, then map over it to get the values. Like below:

```
const tags = this.props.reviewData.reviews.tags;  
const tags_values = ( tags ? tags.map((tag) => (tag.value ? tag.value : '' ) : []); // this an array of the tags values.
```

Your code does not return what you want because the tags attributes is an array of objects, so to get the tag values you have to map over it as I did above.

Hope this helped.